# .net library for PDF creation that can handle vector (eps) images

Tags: image, pdf, vector, eps

Are there any libraries that lets you include vector based eps files (eg Illustrator eps images) in a PDF file - I mean not by first rasterizing the image to a .PNG file, in fact we need to retain the resolution independent vector format.
We are working on a solution that lets users create hi-res printable documents online. Their lay-out can include text and images in various formats. They can upload their own art which we then convert to a low-res onscreen image. If they upload a EPS file, we need to include the resolution independent original file in the final production document, which would be a PDF document.
Most PDF creation libraries seem lack support for vector eps images...

Comment: Generating a raster of the eps at print resolution for the production pdf file is not an option i presume?

Comment: Sadly no, because rasterized images can't contain a clipping path so you always end up with a non transparant (white) rectangular background, which isn't what you want when the illustration is placed on a coloured background.

Comment: You still have the option of generating a rgb (or cmyk) raster image + a 1bpp mask but I agree : that it isn't an optimal process.